# Source table has primary key and should I need to create in destination table

Tags: sql

I am loading the data from source table to destination table where primary key exists on the source table. My question is do I need to create the primary key in destination table as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps. Why do you copy data from one table to another?

Comment: I need to create a incremental load from source to destination table for reporting needs. We dont have leverage to access source table for all our needs. To be precise I will jst inserting the new records thats comes into source table on daily basis and load into destination table only respective one day records

Answer (score 0):

From what you've written, it doesn't sound like you need to create a primary key in the destination table. Probably no harm whether you do or don't.